# how to declare and insert into a map of locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have this very simple reader writer lock class. I am trying to create a map of strings and pointers to this readers writers lock. I am aware that there are pthread reader writer locks but this is for a class and I need to implement one on my own. I'm using c++11 threads.

```
    class ReadersWritersLock{
        private:
        mutex mtx;
        condition_variable_any readers_wait;
        condition_variable_any writers_wait;
        int writers;
        int readers;

        public:
        ReadersWritersLock(){
            writers = 0;
            readers = 0;
        }
        void r_lock(){
            mtx.lock();
            while(writers){
                readers_wait.wait(mtx);
            }
            readers++;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
        void r_unlock(){
            mtx.lock();
            readers--;
            if (!readers)
                writers_wait.notify_one();
            mtx.unlock();
        }
        void w_lock(){
             mtx.lock();
             while (readers + writers > 0){
                 writers_wait.wait(mtx);
             }
             writers++;
             mtx.unlock();
         }
         void w_unlock(){
             mtx.lock();
             writers--;
             if (!readers){
                 writers_wait.notify_one();
             }
             if (readers){
                 readers_wait.notify_all();}
             mtx.unlock();
          }
};
```

What I'd like to do is to declare right after the class is:

```
map<string, *ReadersWritersLock> myMap // this doesn't compile
```

But I'm getting: template argument 2 is invalid

and then when I try to insert a lock:

```
ReadersWritersLock *rwlock = new ReadersWritersLock;
pathnameToLocks["abc"] = rwlock; // this is an doesn't compile
```

I'm getting: assignment of read-only location ‘"abc"[myMap]’
If the above operations are illegal because I'm dealing with locks, is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you mean `map<string, ReadersWritersLock*>`?

Comment: `map<string, *ReadersWritersLock>` Don't think you want the `*` there. Maybe after `ReadersWritersLock`, but that's iffy, too. Probably don't want a pointer at all.

Comment: wow, yeah, that makes a world of difference, so stupid

Comment: If not using pointers, you will need to use `std::map::emplace` to assign, and possibly define a move-constructor for your class.  You might also want to define some interfaces to make the read and write locks meet the requirements of _BasicLockable_.  That way you can use it with `std::unique_lock` and others.